# scala/spark filter dataframe with multiple conditions using sql

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I need to filter df before upsert. Df does not have an index column and every row is different:

The Data frame looks like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+--------+---+
| Col1| Col2| Col3| Col4| Col5|
+---+---+---+---+--------+---+
|  Area| null|  null| null| null|
|  Data| null|  XRP 36| null| null|
|  2020-01-02| 2020-01-03| 2020-01-04| 2020-01-05| null|
|  SUM |  null| null| null| null|
|  0.5 |  0.8|  .5| 0.2| 13|
|  Area | null|  null| null| null|
|  Price | null|  null| null| null|
|  4000VBG | 4000VBG|  4000VBG| 4000VBG| null|
|  Data | null|  FDX 45| null| null|
|  2020-02-02 | 2020-02-03| 2020-02-04| 2020-02-05| null|
|  SUM |  null| null| null| null|
|  0.5 |  0.8|  .5| 0.2| 13|
+---+---+---+---+--------+
```

I need output like this:

```
 +---+---+---+---+--------+---+
| Col1| Ccol2| Col3| Col4| C5|
+---+---+---+---+--------+---+
|  Data| null|  XRP 36| null| null|
|  2020-01-02| 2020-01-03| 2020-01-04| 2020-01-05| null|
|  0.5|  0.8|  .5| 0.2| 13|
|  Data| null|  FDX 45| null| null|
|  2020-02-02| 2020-02-03| 2020-02-04| 2020-02-05| null|
|  0.5|  0.8|  .5| 0.2| 13|
+---+---+---+---+--------+
```

so for every row that has "Data" I need Data, Date and Values .

Thanks

Comment: How does row 1,2 and 3 or other have 5 columns but only 4 values ?

Comment: @koiralo some rows have 5 columns and some 4 and some only 1

Comment: how can dataframe have that? can you share the df.show(false) result ?

Comment: Sorry, I have 25 columns, and rows that don't have values in the 5th column are null, will edit my question

Comment: And add expected result and logic to get the result accordingly

Comment: Could you please explain `every row that has "Data" I need Data, Date and Values`? It seems to be a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I need a row where the first column has "Data" , a row below that "Data" row, and a row three rows below the "Data" row

Comment: How is your data ordered ?

Comment: It is not ordered, I read it from CSV, there is no column I can order it by

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm . . . I think you just want `not null`:

```
select t.*
from t
where col2 is not null or col3 is not null or col4 is not null;
```

Comment: There are some rows that are not null and I don't need them, df has more than 20000 rows and I have more than 1000 CSV files to read, but all have same structure for rows I need

Comment: @Toni0123 . . . That is not the question you asked here.  This answers the question that you did ask.  If you have a different question ask a **new** question.